# My Laravel Redirect Functionality is Screwed Up

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-4

I cannot pass any variable along with my redirect command. The following test works fine on a vanilla install of L4 and displays 'got it!', but in my current project it does not pass any variables.

```
Route::get('redirect', function()
{
    return Redirect::to('destination')->with('myvar', 'got it!');
});

Route::get('destination', function()
{
    return Session::get('myvar');
});
```

This explains why I cannot pass errors or repopulate forms upon validation failure. The odd behavior that it shows is a redirect message at the top of the screen -- "Redirecting to " and it gives the url. This message is generated from /vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RedirectResponse.php. Does this ring a bell with anyone? Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: What is your session configuration?

Comment: <?php

return array(

 'driver' => 'file',


 'lifetime' => 120,
 'expire_on_close' => false,


 'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',


 'connection' => null,


 'table' => 'sessions',


 'lottery' => array(2, 100),


 'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

 'path' => '/',


 'domain' => null,
 'secure' => false,

);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take very close look at your source code and views. Usually you see this "Redirecting to" message flashing when your script send characters to your browser before the redirection headers.

As an example: you might have spaces, line breaks or chars before `<?` or after a `?>`, or something else (like `echo`) that does the same.

Comment: Af far as I can see I do not have any ?> at the end of a php file in my site.

Comment: It was just an example. As I said, many other things can send characters to browser before the headers. A simple `echo` can do that.

Comment: Holy crap that was it!! I found a config file that had a space before the <?php tag! I hate this, there should be a way to check for this in php. Yikes, good call!!

Comment: Yeah, happened to me more than once, now I just know... :)